# use php dom parser inside another class - ERROR: Call to a member function on a non-object

Tags: php

I'm using PHP simple dom parser http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm. 
I'm able to successfully use it and remove an html tag with specific id by doing

```
$html = str_get_html('<div><div class="two">two</div></div>');     
function test($str, $class){
    $e = $str->find($class,0);
    $e->outertext = '';
    echo $str->outertext;
}
test($html, '#two');
```

My problem is when i try to use the function inside another php class. It doesn't work. Here's what i did

```
$html = new simple_html_dom(); //initialized the object

class Someclass {
    public function test($wrap, $class){
        global $html;
        $html->load($wrap);
        $e = $html->find($class,0);
        $e->outertext = '';
        echo $html->outertext;
    }    
}
```

I'm getting an error **Fatal error: Call to a member function load() on a non-object**
What am i doing wrong. I'm i calling this correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create new instance of html dom parser inside your function:

```
// include dom parser file first
class Someclass {
    public function test($wrap, $class){
        $html = new simple_html_dom(); //initialized the object
        $html->load($wrap);
        $e = $html->find($class,0);
        $e->outertext = '';
        echo $html->outertext;
    }    
}
```

Also make sure that you have included the html parser class in above class using `include` or `require`.

BTW, if dom parser is going to be used in various functions of your class, you should create class level variable and store new instance of it when constructing your class like this:

```
// include dom parser file first
class Someclass {
    protected $html_parser = null;

    public function __construct(){
        $this->html_parser = new simple_html_dom();
    }    
}
```

Now you will be able to use `$this->html_parser` in different functions of your class.

Comment: In your second example. Do i load by doing `$this->html_parser->load($wrap)`

Comment: @Pinkie: Yes you are right :) It is basically same dom parser variable similar to your `$html` variable :)

Comment: @Pinkie: It looks fine to me. Chances are that there could be some other problem. Make sure that file path is also correct that you are including.

Comment: Thanks sarfaz, That worked for me. I had other issues with the code that was preventing this from working. All good now.